# How to write a poem with commentary?

Tags: footnotes, verse, poetry

I would like to get a layout like the one in the figure:[image: Commentary and poem]

There's no need of not justifying the text of the commentary, but every line must be linked with its comment below. Is there a package I can use, and what should I do?

Comment: Start with this  minimal working example (MWE):  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{foo} foo
\item \label{bar} bar baz 
\end{enumerate}
\hrule 
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\ref{foo}] \textbf{foo:} \lipsum[2]
\item[\ref{bar}] \textbf{bar:} \lipsum[3] 
\item[\ref{bar}] \textbf{baz:} \lipsum[4] 
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}` ....and then ask for specific problems to reach the desired layout, showing your own MWE. In the actual form the question is too vague and broad.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: The package `reledmac` has this among its features.

Comment: I am sorry for not having specified anything. Here is what I think you need:

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{verse}
 \poemlines{3}
\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
Il primo giorno che noi la vedemmo,\\
...
di meno due sovvenne a c\"iascuno.\\!
\end{verse}

Answer (score 5):

Something like this? I use the `verse` package, and define a `commentaries` environment, base on a customised description environment, with `\item`replaced by a `\scolio`  command with two arguments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, italian, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{gillius2}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol, verse, changepage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thickhrulefill[1][0.8pt]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height #1\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{commentaries}{%
{\color{Tomato}\thickhrulefill}\vspace{-1.5ex}
\sffamily\begin{multicols*}{2}\description[leftmargin=1.5em , labelwidth=\dimexpr 1.5em-\labelsep \relax, style=unboxed, font=\sffamily\bfseries]}%
{\enddescription\end{multicols*}}

\renewcommand\poemtitlefont{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\gilliustwocondensed}
 \newcommand{\mypoemtitle}[1]{%
 \begin{adjustwidth}{-\dimexpr1in+\oddsidemargin}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\oddsidemargin+1in-\paperwidth}
\raisebox{\dimexpr\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+1in+11pt-\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
\parbox{\paperwidth}{\color{Tomato!75}\rule{\paperwidth}{10pt}\vspace{-10pt}\par\noindent\setlength\fboxsep{10pt}%
 \colorbox{Tomato!75}{\parbox{0.3\paperwidth}{\color{white}\poemtitlefont~\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}}%
 \end{adjustwidth}
 }
\settowidth{\versewidth}{Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita}
\NewDocumentCommand{\scolio}{r[]m}{\item[\ref{#1}] \textbf{#2}:}

\begin{document}

\mypoemtitle{Inferno\quad Canto I}
\centering\begin{minipage}{1.3\versewidth}
\poemlines{1}%
\setlength\vleftskip{-20pt}
\verselinenumbersleft
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]%\centering
\vrightskip0cm
 Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita \label{v1}\\
mi ritrovai per una selva oscura \label{v2}\\
ché la diritta via era smarrita. \label{v3} \\
 Ahi quanto a dir qual era è cosa dura \label{v4}\\
esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte \label{v5}\\
che nel pensier rinova la paura! \label{v6}\\
 Tant'è amara che poco è più morte; \label{v7}\\
ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai, \label{v8}\\
dirò de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte. \label{v9}\\
\end{verse}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{6ex}\par
\begin{commentaries}
  \scolio[v1]{Nel mezzo …vita} il significato più ovvio sulla scorta di un passo del Convivio (IV XXIII 6–10) è che il verso significhi \textcolor{Tomato}{all’età di trenta cinque anni}. Dice infatti il poeta nell’passo citato: «Tutte le terrene vite… convengono essere quasi ad imagine d’arco assimiglianti… lo punto sommo di questo arco… ne li più io credo [sia] tra il trentesino et il quarantesimo anno, e io credo che ne li perfettamente naturati esso ne sia nel trentacinquesimo anno».

  %
  \scolio[v2]{mi ritrovai} il poeta ha coscienza di aver deviato dalla retta via e si rende conto della propria condizione.

\scolio[v2]{per una selva oscura} in una (cfr. Cavalcanti, Io non pensava, v. 20: «~l’anima sento per lo cor tremare~»). È importante ricordare, per comprendere il senso simbolico di questa selva, il passo del Convivio (IV XXIV 12): «~Così l’adolescente, che entra ne la selva erronea di questa vita, non saprebbe tenere lo buono cammino, se da li suoi maggiori non li fosse mostrato~». Essa è dunque «~la selva erronea di questa vita~», la vita peccaminosa, dominata dai sensi, nella quale il poeta a un tratto si rende conto di essere entrato (mi ritrovai), am, come sarà detto al v. 11, senza accorgersene, perché il suo animo eera come intorpidito (pien di sonno) dal peccato. Non dobbiamo però che in Dante, accanto al motivo autobiografico, sta una implicazionedi natura politico-religiosa. Quindi per il personnagio Dante la selva significa un momento di traviamento spirituale da cui lo libereranno la considerazione delle gravi conseguenze del peccato (Inferno) e, attraverso l’espiazione (Purgatorio), la speranza dell’eterna beatudine (Paradiso).
La nascita di Dante nel 1265 pone dunque il momento dell’azione del poema nel 1300 (dat che anche per altre indicazioni è ormai comunemente accolta).

\scolio[v3]{ché} l’edizione critica di Petrocchi restituice alla particella il significato causale, che «~consente subito […] di indicare la causa del viaggio, e quindi l’evento motore dell’itinerario dantesco nei regni dell’oltretomba» (Petrocchi, II 3).

\scolio[v4]{dura} ardua, dolorosa.

\scolio[v5]{selva selvaggia} si noti la figura retorica della paronomasia o «annominazione», che unisce due parole di suono uguale o affine, conforme al gusto retorico medievale (vedi più avanti v. 36).

\scolio[v5]{forte} difficile. La dittologia (figura retorica che prevede una coppia di elementi omologhi collegati dalla congiunzione «e») aspra e forte ritornerà in Pg II.

\end{commentaries}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Incredibly precise and useful. I sincerely and deeply thank you for your time! I still would like to specify something. How could I keep automatically the verses and their commentary in the same page, making the program vary the number of verses in a page in function of the length of the commentary?

Comment: @fscarri: I really have no idea. If that is possible, it's far beyond my skills. Personally I would do it by hand. Of  course, if it's for the *Divine Comedy* or Ovid's *Metamorphoses*, it may be a little long…